# Retain dropdownlist selected value after post to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

I have dropdownlist in my view and load this dropdown with values from controller. On change event I need to pass data to controller, after that the dropdownlist loaded fresh. But I want to keep the selected value after post to controller. My jQuery is following :

```
$.ajax({ 
        url: "/TimesheetModels/GetUsersForTimesheet",
        type: "Get", 
        success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {                
                opt =  new Option(data[i].First_Name, data[i].EmpId);
                $('#ddlUsers').append(opt); //Load drodown list while page load
            } 
        } 
    });

 $('#ddlUsers').change(function () {
        alert($(this).val());
        var empId = $(this).val();
        startDate = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate').startOf('week');
        window.location.href = "/TimesheetModels/TimesheetApproval?selectDate=" + convertDate(startDate) + "&empId=" + empId; //Pass data to controller
        alert(empId); // i get this alert before pass to controller
         $('#ddlUsers').val(empId);
    });
```

In controller i have this aciton,

```
 public ActionResult TimesheetApproval(string SelectDate,string empId)
        {
            DateTime startDate;
            if (!DateTime.TryParse(SelectDate, out startDate))
                startDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek);

            int EmpId;
            if (empId != null)
                EmpId = Convert.ToInt32(empId);
            else
            {
                 EmpId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["EmpId"].ToString());
            }

            string startDateCalendar = Convert.ToString(startDate.ToString("ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss")) + " GMT+0530";
            ViewData["startDateCalendar"] = startDateCalendar;

            DateTime endDate = startDate.AddDays(6);


            List<TimesheetMatrix> _timesheetList = _timesheetDetailViewModel.GetAllProjectTasks(startDate, endDate, EmpId);


            return View(_timesheetList);
        }
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: 1. Is this `asp.net`? 2. You are not posting to the controller you are redirecting the browser, although your JavaScript does run after the relocation everything is lost as the whole page is re-requested. I would suggest that you use an AJAX POST similar to the one you have already done rather that using `window.location.href`

Comment: I am using MVC and want to pass data to controller

Comment: Yes it is MVC but MVC is a concept... are you using asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

you should do a ajax post while change dropdown as follow:-

```
 $('#ddlUsers').change(function () {
        alert($(this).val());
        var empId = $(this).val();
        startDate = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate').startOf('week');

   $.ajax({ 
        url: "/TimesheetModels/TimesheetApproval?selectDate=" + convertDate(startDate) + "&empId=" + empId,
        type: "Get", 
        success: function (data) {
            //Any logic
        } 
    });

        alert(empId); // i get this alert before pass to controller
         $('#ddlUsers').val(empId);
    });
```

In this way, you can retain the dropdown.

Comment: i tried this..now, the dropdwon value is set. but the page data is not loaded from controller action

Comment: what data you need to refreshed in page?

Comment: I update the question with my action in controller. please check

Comment: so you are fetching timesheet based on selected user and date. In that case above mentioned solution will not work.